# Cannot find module 'postcss-import'

Tags: tailwind-css

[error after run project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdTAh.png)

I wrote this in global.css :

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

@layer components{
    .icon{
        @apply hidden xl:inline-flex p-2 h-10 w-10  bg-gray-200 rounded-full text-gray-70 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300;
    }
}
```

and then I got error from the image

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package?

```
npm install --save-dev postcss-import
```

or

```
yarn add --dev postcss-import
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . I have added the package . But now there is a new error .it says :Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/nesting'

Comment: that's a similar error, you haven't installed it, do this `npm install -D postcss-nesting`

Comment: please check  the screenshot of global.css I attached to this question . I think there is a syntax error I have done but can't understant how to fix.